# Choosing a specific item in an array in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select a particular item from an array in jQuery, and I need to perform some further jQuery processing. Like this:

```
    $(".checkBoxes").toArray()[i].append($(this).clone());
```

The object returned from the toArray()[i] does not support append, although if I remove the toArray()[i] then it does support append.

How do I select the i'th element from the array and perform an append on it?

Thanks, S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [`.eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function to get the element from the corresponding index,

```
$(".checkBoxes").eq(i).append($(this).clone());
```

Or you can use [`:eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector

```
$(".checkBoxes:eq("+ i +")").append($(this).clone());
```